# More convenient way to use comparators in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin [comparison operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#comparison) can be used instead of `compareTo` method:

```
a > b   // a.compareTo(b) > 0
a < b   // a.compareTo(b) < 0
a >= b  // a.compareTo(b) >= 0
a <= b  // a.compareTo(b) <= 0
```

It's convenient and makes comparisons a lot more readable. However, these operators cannot be used if there is no suitable `compareTo` method, but there is  a suitable `Comparator`.

To make it possible to use them in this case, I've created a `use` extension function for a `Comparator` interface:

```
inline fun <T, R> Comparator<T>.use(block: ComparatorDSL<T>.() -> R) =
    ComparatorDSL(this).run(block)
```

Where `ComparatorDSL` is the following class:

```
inline class ComparatorDSL<T>(private val comparator: Comparator<T>) {
    operator fun T.compareTo(other: T) = comparator.compare(this, other)
}
```

Now I can use it like this:

```
comparator.use { a > b } // comparator.compare(a, b) > 0
```

**Questions:**

- Is `comparator.use { a > b }` more readable than `comparator.compare(a, b) > 0`?
- Is it a good idea to replace `use` with `invoke` operator or make this function `infix`?
- Any improvement suggestions that you can think of

Comment: Like the idea. Only thing I don't like is the name. Use in my eyes refers to the Closeable- interface. Maybe check is better, or just compare?

Comment: @tieskedh That's a good point. But `check` doesn't make much sense if you use it not for one comparison but wrap the whole function with it. Maybe it's better to remove the name completely and use the `invoke` operator.

Comment: I don't like that idea, as this implies that the main goal for the comparator is to function as an predicate, while I think sorting is as important as checking...

Comment: I like the implementation for this use-case. The naming is always difficult, but I would suggest 1. 'test' as in Javas Predicate, or 2. 'isTrue' / 'isTrueFor' to indicate a boolean result

Answer (score 1):

### Is comparator.use { a > b } more readable than comparator.compare(a, b) > 0?

Readability is relative and more a point of view. Usually something is considered more readable, the more people say it is.

In my personal opinion both solutions are easy to read, while I like the syntax of the first more. Actually something very similar exists in the language already: [compareBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html#compareby)

```
list.sortedWith(
  compareBy{ it.a }.thenBy { it.b }.thenByDescending { it.c }
)
```

It has all combinations you need and provides a nice, well readable syntax.

### Is it a good idea to replace `use` with `invoke` operator or make this function `infix`?

1. `use` isntead of `invoke`

It is opinion based, just like readability. Its up to you and your team.

2. Infix

Making a function an `infix` function is just another customisation option for your syntax. The only important thing to remeber is:

> Infix function calls have lower precedence than the arithmetic
>   operators, type casts, and the rangeTo operator. The following
>   expressions are equivalent:
>
> - 1 shl 2 + 3 is equivalent to 1 shl (2 + 3)
> - 0 until n * 2 is equivalent to 0 until (n * 2)
> - xs union ys as Set<> is equivalent to xs union (ysas Set<>)
>
> On the other hand, infix function call's precedence is
>   higher than that of the boolean operators && and ||, is- and
>   in-checks, and some other operators. These expressions are equivalent
>   as well:
>
> - a && b xor c is equivalent to a && (b xor c)
> - a xor b in c isequivalent to (a xor b) in c

[Kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation)

-

### Any improvement suggestions that you can think of

Strongly consider to use [compareBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html#compareby) like described before.

Comment: compareBy gives great ways to create the comparators.
The post uses the comparetors to create predicates, to get a boolean value.
Therefor, it's not a replacement for compareBy, but an addition to the Compareable interfaces.
I do like your explanation for infix-functions; 
This means that there aren't serious implications in this case.